# Unit Tests on Method that uses GetEntitiesAync (DocumentDB)

Tags: linq, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq, azure-cosmosdb

After mocking `DocumentDBRepository` class with its `GetEntitiesAsync()` method in the unit test, it is return a `null` value which is not I expect it to return.

Here's my method that I need to test

```
 public async Task<Books> GetBooksByBookIdAsyncByLinq(string bookId)
    {

        var books = await _individualRepository.GetEntitiesAsync(t => t.BookID == bookId);

        if (individualResponse.Any())
        {
            return individualResponse.FirstOrDefault();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Here's the unit test of this method, **noticed that I set up the `GetEntitiesAsync()` method and expect it to return a book value**. But it is returning `null` when I ran it:

```
  [Fact]
        public void Test_GetBooksByBookIdAsyncByLinq()
        {
            //Arrange
            var bookID = "000";

            //Mock DocumentDBRepository
            var mockDocumentDBRepository = new Mock<IRepository<Book>>();
            var expected = Get_BookValue();
            mockDocumentDBRepository.Setup(x => x.GetEntitiesAsync(x => x.BookID == bookID))
                                    .Returns(Task.FromResult(expected));
            var component = new BookComponent(mockDocumentDBRepository.Object);

            //Act
            var result = component.GetBooksByBookIdAsyncByLinq(bookID);
            //Assert
            result.Result.Should().NotBeNull().And.
                 BeOfType<Book>();
        }


        private Book Get_BookValue(){

         IEnumerable<Book> result = new List<Book>
                    { new Book
                    { BookID = "000", BookName = "TestSourceSystemName" } };
                    return result;
        }
```

When I ran the unit test and debug inside the `GetBooksByBookIdAsyncByLinq()` method, it is not getting any results from the `books` variable and return `null` without any error.

The interesting thing is, when I change the `GetEntitiesAsync()` method to `RunSQLQueryAsync()` method, which means using SQL query instead of Linq, the unit test is returning the correct result.

Here's the method I am testing:

```
public async Task<Books> GetBooksByBookIdAsyncBySQL(string bookId)
        {

            var books = await _individualRepository.RunSQLQueryAsync("select * from c where c.BookID ==" + bookId);

            if (individualResponse.Any())
            {
                return individualResponse.FirstOrDefault();
            }

            return null;
        }
```

And here's the unit test for this method, **noticed that I set up the RunQueryAsync() method and expect to return a book value. And it works**:

```
        [Fact]
                public void Test_GetBooksByBookIdAsyncBySQL()
                {
                    //Arrange
                    var bookID = "000";

                    var sqlQuery = "select * from c where c.BookID ==" + bookId;

                    //Mock DocumentDBRepository
                    var mockDocumentDBRepository = new Mock<IRepository<Book>>();
                    var expected = Get_BookValue();
//mockDocumentDBRepository.Setup(x => x.GetEntitiesAsync(x => x.BookID == bookID))
//                                        .Returns(Task.FromResult(expected));
                    mockDocumentDBRepository.Setup(x => x.RunQueryAsync(sqlQuery))
                                            .Returns(Task.FromResult(expected));
                    var component = new BookComponent(mockDocumentDBRepository.Object);

                    //Act
                    var result = component.GetBooksByBookIdAsyncBySQL(bookID);
                    //Assert
                    result.Result.Should().NotBeNull().And.
                         BeOfType<Book>();
                }
    private Book Get_BookValue(){

     IEnumerable<Book> result = new List<Book>
                { new Book
                { BookID = "000", BookName = "TestSourceSystemName" } };
                return result;
    }
```

**So I am thinking maybe the way I mock `GetEntitiesAsync()` method is incorrect**. But I am not sure why...

Here are the `RunQueryAsync()` and `GetEntitiesAsync()` methods for reference:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetEntitiesAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
                IDocumentQuery<T> query = GetQueryByPredicate(predicate);
                List<T> results = new List<T>();
                while (query.HasMoreResults)
                {
                    results.AddRange(await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>());
                }
                return results;
        }

   public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> RunQueryAsync(string queryString)
        {
            IDocumentQuery<T> query = GetQueryBySQL(queryString);

            List<T> results = new List<T>();

            while (query.HasMoreResults)
            {
                results.AddRange(await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>());
            }
            return results;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Setup` method tries to look at the arguments passed into your method, and only match the specified behavior if those arguments are the same.

When you use `GetQueryBySQL`, Moq is able to detect that the `sqlQuery` string is the same (as in `object.Equals()`) as what's passed in, so it works correctly.

When you use `GetEntitiesAsync`, Moq looks at the two Expressions and thinks they are different because Expression comparison is based on memory equality. So even though the two `x => x.BookID == bookID`s look the same to you and me, they are different Expressions at runtime.

Try using `It.IsAny<>()` instead:

```
mockDocumentDBRepository
    .Setup(x => x.GetEntitiesAsync(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Book, bool>>()))
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(expected));
```

Supposing you get that working, you can use `Callback` or other strategies to test that the expression passed into GetEntitiesAsync has the behavior you're expecting it to have.

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you so much!!! I used 'mockDocumentDBRepository
    .Setup(x => x.GetEntitiesAsync(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Book, bool>>()))
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(expected));' because the param of the `GetEntitiesAsync` function is `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`

Comment: Of course, that makes sense. I updated my answer accordingly.